# How can I control the transparency inside a pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots, transparency

I am trying to plot a 3D scatter plot with a decision boundary and I'm trying to put the cyan plane above the blue points but they end up on top instead, I've tried modifying the opacity and ordering the plots but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=7,ymin=-2,ymax=6,zmin=-3,zmax=9,axis background/.style={fill=gray!10},view={13}{5},xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$x^2+y^2$, z label style={rotate=-90},
,scatter/classes={
a={mark=*,color=blue},b={mark=*,color=red}}]
%Red scatter
\addplot3+[
only marks,scatter src =explicit symbolic,
scatter,mark size=2.9pt]
coordinates{
(5.4,5.45,5.952500000000001) [b]
(4.7,5.4,3.8900000000000006) [b]
(4.3,5.8,4.769999999999998) [b]
(3.6,5.9,4.8500000000000005) [b]
(3,5.77,4.774899999999998) [b]
(6,4.7,6.289999999999999) [b]
(6,4.2,5.539999999999999) [b]
(1.6,4.7,5.41) [b]
(5,4.5,2.329999999999999) [b]
(2,5.4,5.780000000000001) [b]
(1,3.5,7.330000000000001) [b]
(1.5,2.5,6.280000000000001) [b]
(2.1,2.8,3.370000000000001) [b]
(2.1,2.8,3.370000000000001) [b]
(6.4,3.8,7.300000000000001) [b]
(1.2,4.5,6.89) [b]
(3.67,1.47,4.9738000000000016) [b]
(6,2.5,6.7299999999999995) [b]
(6.2,3,6.74) [b]
(5,2.55,3.0125) [b]
(4.89,1.7,5.416099999999998) [b]
(2.8,1.5,5.650000000000001) [b]
(2.5,2.3,3.4000000000000012) [b]
(2,2.071,5.543641000000001) [b]
(4,2,2.9800000000000004) [b]
(3.5,2.5,2.4800000000000004) [b]
(3,2,3.380000000000001) [b]
(4,5.3, 2.6499999999999986) [b]
(4.4,2.3,2.4500000000000015) [b]
(2.23,5.001,3.8535010000000014) [b]
(2.5,2.8,2.250000000000001) [b]
(1.5,3,5.330000000000001) [b]
(1.5,4,4.930000000000001) [b]
(1.77,3.47,3.777800000000001) [b]
(5.2,4.9,3.6900000000000004) [b]
(3.45,5,1.7524999999999995) [b]
(2,4.2,3.1400000000000006) [b]
(2.6,5.3,3.7699999999999987) [b]
(2.4,4.6,2.4999999999999996) [b]
(3.24,5.3,2.7715999999999985) [b]
(5.3,3,3.049999999999999) [b]
(5.3,3.5,2.5999999999999988) [b]
(5.7,3.8,4.01) [b]
(6,3.5,5.329999999999999) [b]
(5.7,2.7,5) [b]
(5.4,4.3,3.25) [b]
(4.5,5,2.329999999999999) [b]};
%blue scatter
\addplot3+[
only marks,scatter src =explicit symbolic,
scatter,mark size=2.9pt]
coordinates{
(3.17,3,0.7709000000000006) [a]
(2.9,3.27,0.8249000000000006) [a]
(2.8,3.63,0.8149000000000006) [a]
(2.9,4,0.7300000000000003) [a]
(3.2,4.1,0.4099999999999996) [a]
(3.6,4.47,0.6028999999999993) [a]
(4,4.4,0.5800000000000002) [a]
(4.3,4.2,0.6099999999999997) [a]
(4.2,3.4,0.3400000000000002) [a]
(4.5,3.8,0.6499999999999996)  [a]
(4,3,0.5800000000000002) [a]
(4,3.7,0.0899999999999999) [a]
(3.7,4.1,0.1599999999999996) [a]
(4.5,3.2,0.8899999999999997) [a]
(3.5,3.5,0.08000000000000014) [a]
(3.7,3.3,0.16000000000000028) [a]
(3.7,3.7,0) [a]
(3.1,3.7,0.3600000000000001) [a]
(3.1,3.4,0.4500000000000003) [a]
(3.5,3.2,0.2900000000000001) [a]
(4.2,3.9,0.2899999999999999) [a]
(3.2,4.37,0.6988999999999999) [a]};
%Boundary
\addplot3[samples=100,domain=1:6.5, domain y =-2:6, color=cyan, fill opacity=0.2](x,y,{1.3});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the result]
[image: And the view at {0}{0}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reorder the plots such there the most hidden ones come first and add `clip mode=individual` you get

[image]

Why `clip mode=individual`? Not sure I understand this but it is mentioned in the context of `mark layer`, which I originally thought would be the relevant key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=7,ymin=-2,ymax=6,zmin=-3,zmax=9,axis background/.style={fill=gray!10},view={13}{5},xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel=$x^2+y^2$, z label style={rotate=-90},
,scatter/classes={
a={mark=*,color=blue},b={mark=*,color=red}},
clip mode=individual]
%blue scatter
\addplot3+[
only marks,scatter src =explicit symbolic,
scatter,mark size=2.9pt]
coordinates{
(3.17,3,0.7709000000000006) [a]
(2.9,3.27,0.8249000000000006) [a]
(2.8,3.63,0.8149000000000006) [a]
(2.9,4,0.7300000000000003) [a]
(3.2,4.1,0.4099999999999996) [a]
(3.6,4.47,0.6028999999999993) [a]
(4,4.4,0.5800000000000002) [a]
(4.3,4.2,0.6099999999999997) [a]
(4.2,3.4,0.3400000000000002) [a]
(4.5,3.8,0.6499999999999996)  [a]
(4,3,0.5800000000000002) [a]
(4,3.7,0.0899999999999999) [a]
(3.7,4.1,0.1599999999999996) [a]
(4.5,3.2,0.8899999999999997) [a]
(3.5,3.5,0.08000000000000014) [a]
(3.7,3.3,0.16000000000000028) [a]
(3.7,3.7,0) [a]
(3.1,3.7,0.3600000000000001) [a]
(3.1,3.4,0.4500000000000003) [a]
(3.5,3.2,0.2900000000000001) [a]
(4.2,3.9,0.2899999999999999) [a]
(3.2,4.37,0.6988999999999999) [a]};
%Boundary
\addplot3[samples=100,
domain=1:6.5, domain y =-2:6, color=cyan,opacity=0.5](x,y,{1.3});
%Red scatter
\addplot3+[
only marks,scatter src =explicit symbolic,
scatter,mark size=2.9pt]
coordinates{
(5.4,5.45,5.952500000000001) [b]
(4.7,5.4,3.8900000000000006) [b]
(4.3,5.8,4.769999999999998) [b]
(3.6,5.9,4.8500000000000005) [b]
(3,5.77,4.774899999999998) [b]
(6,4.7,6.289999999999999) [b]
(6,4.2,5.539999999999999) [b]
(1.6,4.7,5.41) [b]
(5,4.5,2.329999999999999) [b]
(2,5.4,5.780000000000001) [b]
(1,3.5,7.330000000000001) [b]
(1.5,2.5,6.280000000000001) [b]
(2.1,2.8,3.370000000000001) [b]
(2.1,2.8,3.370000000000001) [b]
(6.4,3.8,7.300000000000001) [b]
(1.2,4.5,6.89) [b]
(3.67,1.47,4.9738000000000016) [b]
(6,2.5,6.7299999999999995) [b]
(6.2,3,6.74) [b]
(5,2.55,3.0125) [b]
(4.89,1.7,5.416099999999998) [b]
(2.8,1.5,5.650000000000001) [b]
(2.5,2.3,3.4000000000000012) [b]
(2,2.071,5.543641000000001) [b]
(4,2,2.9800000000000004) [b]
(3.5,2.5,2.4800000000000004) [b]
(3,2,3.380000000000001) [b]
(4,5.3, 2.6499999999999986) [b]
(4.4,2.3,2.4500000000000015) [b]
(2.23,5.001,3.8535010000000014) [b]
(2.5,2.8,2.250000000000001) [b]
(1.5,3,5.330000000000001) [b]
(1.5,4,4.930000000000001) [b]
(1.77,3.47,3.777800000000001) [b]
(5.2,4.9,3.6900000000000004) [b]
(3.45,5,1.7524999999999995) [b]
(2,4.2,3.1400000000000006) [b]
(2.6,5.3,3.7699999999999987) [b]
(2.4,4.6,2.4999999999999996) [b]
(3.24,5.3,2.7715999999999985) [b]
(5.3,3,3.049999999999999) [b]
(5.3,3.5,2.5999999999999988) [b]
(5.7,3.8,4.01) [b]
(6,3.5,5.329999999999999) [b]
(5.7,2.7,5) [b]
(5.4,4.3,3.25) [b]
(4.5,5,2.329999999999999) [b]};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```